# Can you combine z scores from similar but non-identical populations?

Tags: standardization, paired-data

Suppose you have a group of people estimating the heights of trees.  Suppose you have many different types of trees, some trees with a very low height, and others that are very tall.  Suppose each person in the group estimates the height for each type of tree.  Something like the following:

```
            |          col
    Guesser |     Tree  1    Tree 2     Tree 3
 -----------+----------------------------------
          1 |        7m         39m        65m 
          2 |        5m         33m        64m 
          3 |       10m         45m        70m
          4 |        9m         44m        70m
 -----------+----------------------------------
```

Clearly, we may compute z scores for the guesses for each tree, and construct composite scores using covariance, as in the following: http://www.psychassessment.com.au/pdf/mod5.pdf

But the above construction uses paired data, and the covariance of the pairs is used in the construction (for example, guesser 2 is consistently low, and guesser 3 is consistently high).

What happens if you have one group of people guessing for tree 1, a second group of people guessing for tree 2, and a third group of people guessing for tree 3, as in the following:

```
            |          col
    Guesser |     Tree  1    Tree 2     Tree 3
 -----------+----------------------------------
          1 |        7m                        
          2 |        5m                        
          3 |       10m                       
          4 |        9m                       
          5 |                   40m           
          6 |                   35m           
          7 |                   43m
          8 |                            62m
          9 |                            68m
         10 |                            75m
         11 |                            72m
         12 |                            68m
 -----------+----------------------------------
```

In this case, the data is not paired in a meaningful way.  Is there any way to group the z scores you get for the different guesses into a single collection of z scores?